# mySql Date/DateTime default value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a Mysql 5.5 and a table with a column as follow:

```
`VERSION_TS` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

but i'm having difficulties lately i'm getting this exception:

> Incorrect datetime value: '1998-03-20' for column 'VERSION_TS' at row
>   1

when trying to enter values to the table, values of type `Date`, using mySql `MakeDate()`. 
Now, i can't change the function that return `Date`, but i can change the column to `Date`, but then i'll lose the default value. i've tried a couple of things, and then checked the web, and from what i understand in Mysql 5.5 there is no way to do it, but i could be wrong, so i came here to ask:

- Is there a way that i can change the column to a Date and still have
  a default value?
- Also, is there a better way to do approach the problem?

Comment: can you tell in which language the code is written which returns Date.

Comment: @suchit it's written in MySql

Answer (score 1):

I think the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html) is quite clear on this point:

> TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initialized and
>   updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp).

So, this does not apply to `DATE`.  However, you could create a view that does what you want:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*, date(version_ts) as version_date
    from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

if the function which `returns date` is written `in php` then after receiving the `date value` you can do this:

```
  $date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
            echo date_format($date,'Y-m-d H:i:s');// this you can store in mysql table. 

  if not same kind of approach you can apply in the respective language to do the job.
```

OR work with view as Gordon Linoff mentioned.